# force global search Datatables to search on columns that not listed in columns option

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

This is my Datatables jQuery code :

```
$('#allUsersTable').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "responsive": true,
                        ajax: {
                            url :   '{!! route('usersData') !!}',
                            data: function(d){
                                d.level =   $('#levelFilter').val()
                            }
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox', "width": "20px"},
                            {data: 'userPic', name: 'userPic', 'className': 'text-center'},
                            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                            {data: 'level', name: 'level', 'className': 'text-center'},
                            {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', 'className': 'text-center'}
                        ]
                    });
```

As you see I have a **email** column to show email (along with name and family user details).

And this is backend code to fetch columns via [yajra-laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)(some unnecessary parts is omitted ) :

```
$users = User::select(['user_id', 'name', 'family', 'email', 'created_at', 'level']);

        $datatable = app('datatables')->of($users)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')

            ->editColumn('email', function ($user) {
                return '
                        ' . $user->name . ' ' . $user->family . '
                        <div class="en-text"><a href="mailto:' . $user->email . '" target="_blank">' . $user->email . '</a></div>
                    ';
            })

            });

        return $datatable->make(true);
```

We know that global search via Datatables search box only searches on columns listed in **columns** option.

but I want when user enter some characters in global search box,force Datatables to search on name and family column that not included in **columns** option and only used in backend code via **email** column.

How Can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to yajra Answer at https://laracasts.com, solution is simple.

I Should just add hidden column `name` and `family` on My columns definition like this:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox', "width": "20px"},
    {data: 'userPic', name: 'userPic', 'className': 'text-center'},
    {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
    {data: 'level', name: 'level', 'className': 'text-center'},
    {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', 'className': 'text-center'},
    {data: 'name', name: 'name', visible: false},
    {data: 'family', name: 'family', visible: false}
]
```

And this works fine.